# JToggle button not deselectable while Thread sleeping, despite creating new Thread, which should be sleeping

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

```
newToggle1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
        while(ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    player.repeatPlayback();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }}.run();
            }

            if(ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
                new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        player.stopPlayback();
                    }
               }.run();
            }
        }
    });
```

I basically created 2 Itemlisteners for one JToggleButton, one for the release and one for the pressing.

What I want is that my media player that I created as a player object will play the sound. (.repeatPlayback) and then the program waits those 5 seconds for it to play again. And I wanted that if I release the Playback, I will just stop the Playback. The problem arises that the JFrame application generally lags and can not even be closed with the X. It needs to be closed through task manager.

That means that the thread.sleep() command basically sleeps the whole program, making it impossible to operate.

I tried solving it with creating different threads like in the example but it did not work. I also tried scheduleAtFixedRate and it did not work either.

I did not find anything in the internet and also found it to be very specific.
Does anyone know a workaround with another method, than sleep? Or a way this .sleep() can be used?

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting things wrong here.

A **Runnable** is **not** a **Thread**.

The code that you are showing above is **not** doing anything in some extra thread. Everything that happens there is simply running on the Swing Event dispatcher thread! In other words: your code above puts **that** thread into "sleep" that is responsible for all your UI updates. And thus your button becomes unresponsive.

If you want that things happen in their own thread, then well, you have to create and start a **Thread**. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for example.

And the real answer here: multi-threading is complicated enough **without** combining it with Swing/UI programming. So you actually want to step back and spend some time **studying** how Threads work in Java. And then, when you really understand the concepts and how they play together; then you might be ready to use threads in your Swing application. In other words: learn to crawl before trying to run.